# Node fs.writefile from Mac to Windows Share

Tags: node.js, macos, unc, windows-share

While developing a Node application on a Mac, I attempted to write a file into a Windows share using the fs module. It seems to be treating the entire path as a file name, and instead of saving to the file to the proper directory, it saves it to the working directory.

```
const fs = require('fs')

var filePath = '\\\\hostname\\share\\...\\test.txt'

fs.writeFile(filePath, 'testing', function(err){
    if(err) console.error(err)
})
```

Is there a simple way to access this share from a Mac?

Comment: How does the app react to [`path.resolve()`](https://nodejs.org/api/path.html)?

Comment: @zero298 I added `path.resolve(filePath)` to the `fs.writeFile()` call, but I'm seeing the same behavior of it saving the to the working directory with the entire filepath as the filename.